# beforeCreate function is not executing sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

After update my sails (0.10-rc5),

I encountered a problem in beforeCreate function :

```
  beforeCreate : function(values, next){

      console.log("Called beforeCreate User ");
      console.log(values);

      if(!values.password || values.password !== values.confirmation){
          return next({
              err : ["Password doesn't match password confirmation"]
          });
      }

      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
        console.log("call within bcrypt");
          if (err) return next(err);
           bcrypt.hash(values.password, salt, function(err, hash){
              if(err) return next(err);
               values.password = hash;
           });
      });

      Access.findOne()
          .where({ level : values.level })
          .exec(function(err, level){
            console.log("call within findOne");
              if(err) return next(err);
              values.level = level.id;
      });

      console.log("after");    
      console.log(values);
      next();
  }
```

However, the output of the above function is as following :

```
Called beforeCreate User 
{ firstName: 'Quad',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: '11@11.com',
  password: '123456',
  confirmation: '123456',
  level: 'admin',
  id: '2fa1ba1a-ae1c-4380-9107-3c1f6e8eafb3',
  online: false }
after
{ firstName: 'Quad',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: '11@11.com',
  password: '123456',
  confirmation: '123456',
  level: 'admin',
  id: '2fa1ba1a-ae1c-4380-9107-3c1f6e8eafb3',
  online: false }
call within bcrypt
call within findOne
```

As you can see, somehow bcrypt.genSalt(.....){} and Access.findOne(...){} were not called prior to **after**, which is supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is asynchronous code in action...

Node/Sails does not wait for your callbacks to fire before moving on to the the next task.

You need to "nest" your callbacks so that `console.log("AFTER")` is called within the last callback.

Take a look at [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async). It's designed for these types of problems.

Or...

Look into [fibers](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html)

Comment: Does that mean it can call very end **next()** and exit the function prior of the ending of other functions within itself ?

Comment: Exactly. You nailed it. If you are used to synchronous programming, it seems confusing at first. Fibers are really nice for making node "feel" synchronous.

Comment: Thanks @InternalFX. Beforehand, the functions within **beforeCreate** were working fine (executed before the next was called) in 0.9v Sails, I guessed that they have changed.

Comment: @tebesfinwo Thats pretty surprising...The asynchronous nature is built into the very core of nodejs. I would recommend one of the above libraries. Even if it worked before, there was likely a nasty bug/race condition hidden under the surface. If you do not explicitly control the flow of functions, who knows how bad that could turn out.

Comment: Indeed. Okay, I will. Thank you again.